# Stop user navigating forward again

Tags: javascript, html

If a user has visited a page, and returns to the previous page using 'back', how can I ensure they do not go 'forward' again?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with a simple session variable.

### page1.php

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['page2visited'] != 'YES') {

    echo "<a href='page2.php'>Page 2</a>";

}

?>
```

### page2.php

```
<?php

if ($_SESSION['page2visited'] != 'YES') {

    echo "Page 2 Contents!";
    $_SESSION['page2visited'] = 'YES';

}
else {

    echo "You have already viewed this page. You cannot see the contents again.";

}

?>
```

Even if they go forward, this can prevent them from seeing/activating the page2.php content again that they saw/activated previously. (Unless they restart their browser, of course)

Comment: This is a better solution than a javascript once, since the user could just disable javascript

Comment: You can also hide a whole bunch of one-time activating things to page2.php (like writing to a database that indicates the user had already viewed that page - that way if they logged in elsewhere/later on, that $_SESSION['page2visited'] would get reactivated no matter what).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could stop people from using the 'forward' button, people could manually enter the same URL again to go 'forward'.

When you design a web app, you have to assume that users may request any URL and in any order. Design your app so it will work correctly anyways, and so that destructive actions cannot be invoked simply by pressing 'back' or 'forward', or visiting a bookmark.

When the user performs actions which change the state of the application, it is better if those actions are invoked by AJAX calls or posting forms rather than by clicking on links. Remember that GET requests are supposed to be idempotent -- conceptually, a GET is a request to view some information, not to perform an action. Remember also that the concept of a web "page" was originally just that -- like a "page" in a book, which you can look at any number of times. When you turn pages in a book, and then turn back again, you don't expect that some irreversible change will occur simply because you turned the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Look into history.replaceState maybe? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history

Comment: It seems to change the title bar text but not actually stop forwarding again once you've gone back